# Is there a Unix style command like `column` that formats into a table?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface

Is there a command line tool that takes lines of delimiter-separated values and arranges them in a SQL-style table? E.g.,

```
id,name
1,apple
2,banana
3,yogurt
```

into

```
 id |  name    
----+---------
  1 | apple
  2 | banana
  3 | yogurt
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvote?

Comment: After five years of membership and 10K rep you haven't noticed that tool-recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic?

Comment: Actually I never noticed that. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) statement :

**Input file**:

```
$ cat file.scv
id,name
1,apple
2,banana
3,yogurt
```

**Code**:

```
$ cat  ./format-STDIN.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

sep();

while (<>) {
   $. == 2 and sep(); 
   format STDOUT =
|@<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<|
   split /,/
.
   write;
}

sep();

sub sep{ print "+----+-------------+\n"; }
```

**Output**:

```
$ ./format-STDIN.pl file.csv
+----+-------------+
|id  | name        |
+----+-------------+
|1   | apple       |
|2   | banana      |
|3   | yogurt      |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: Maybe someone feels people should be penalized for trying to help someone who asks an "off-topic" question?

Comment: Anyway, I appreciate the time you took to help me.